# MouseEvent not Bubbling up

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mouseevent, styles

I have two intersecting rectangles. I want the opacity of both to change when Mouse hovers over them. It works when mouse is over one of them. But when the mouse is on the intersecting area of the rectangles, only the upper rectangle changes its opacity. Can you please let me know how I can get both the rectangles to change opacity in this case?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTestApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:WpfTestApp="clr-namespace:WpfTestApp" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="RectangleHighlighter" TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.25" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Width="100" Fill="Green" Height="1000" Margin="0,15,0,0" Style="{StaticResource RectangleHighlighter}"/>
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Width="1000" Fill="Green" Height="100" Margin="0,15,0,0" Style="{StaticResource RectangleHighlighter}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact the similar approach that HiTech Magic has described:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="RectangleHighlighter" TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.25" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="MouseOver">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" MouseMove="LayoutRoot_MouseMove">
    <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Width="100" Fill="Green" Height="1000" Margin="0,15,0,0" Style="{StaticResource RectangleHighlighter}"/>
    <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Width="1000" Fill="Green" Height="100" Margin="0,15,0,0" Style="{StaticResource RectangleHighlighter}"/>
</Grid>
```

And its codebehind:

```
    private List<DependencyObject> hitResultsList = new List<DependencyObject>();

    private void LayoutRoot_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Retrieve the coordinate of the mouse position.
        Point pt = e.GetPosition((UIElement)sender);

        // Clear the contents of the list used for hit test results.
        hitResultsList.Clear();

        // Set up a callback to receive the hit test result enumeration.
        VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(LayoutRoot, null,
            new HitTestResultCallback(MyHitTestResult),
            new PointHitTestParameters(pt));

        // Unset all children
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(LayoutRoot); ++i)
        {
            var element = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(LayoutRoot, i) as FrameworkElement;
            if (element != null)
            {
                element.Tag = null;
            }
        }

        // Perform actions on the hit test results list.
        foreach (var dependencyObject in hitResultsList)
        {
            var element = dependencyObject as FrameworkElement;
            if (element != null)
            {
                element.Tag = "MouseOver";
            }
        }
    }

    // Return the result of the hit test to the callback.
    public HitTestResultBehavior MyHitTestResult(HitTestResult result)
    {
        // Add the hit test result to the list that will be processed after the enumeration.
        hitResultsList.Add(result.VisualHit);

        // Set the behavior to return visuals at all z-order levels.
        return HitTestResultBehavior.Continue;
    }
```

Of course its better to add some special attached properties and behaviours for this case.

Comment: Thanks Kreol for the reply. As I mentioned in comment to HiTech, I am more inclined for a xaml only solution. If you can suggest a xaml only solution it will be great else I will try this.

Comment: Unfortunately I guess there are no "xaml-only" solution for this task. So what I'd suggest you - is just separate all these code-behind to a special attached property (behavior) for a container control and of course add some attached property instead of Tag that is used in the my example. In this way you would be able to use these attached properties from XAML without code-behind.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your hover handler to the parent grid instead, make both Rectangles have IsHitTestVisible=False and use [VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838402%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) to determine what object was actually under the mouse (1 or more).

If you must have it style-based, Mario Vernari's suggestion will work, but the hover will trigger anywhere in the grid and not just over the rectangles.

*This strikes me as a very useful idea for an attached Behaviour. The behaviour would implement the code outlined above, but would trigger hover events on the child objects so you could still do it using styles... will have to give that a try.*

Comment: Thanks HiTech for the reply. I am more inclined for a xaml only solution. Can you suggest any? If not possible I will try this.

Comment: @Souvik Basu: *Xaml-only* means you will need to emulate existing events by some new means. I would try creating a Behaviour to generate the events (or state changes).

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply the style to the Grid element.

Comment: Thanks Mario for the reply. But this will not serve my purpose as I want the rectangles highlighted only when mouse hovers over them and not over the grid.

Comment: The grid has no background color (i.e. null), so all the mouse event are not captured. If you try to hover the grid off the rectangles, you won't have any fading (no events). However, unless you keep the background as null, "Transparent" is NOT the same!

Comment: Note: I've tried right now on WPF and it works perfectly. However, I didn't try for Silverlight.

Comment: when i set the style on grid instead of the rectangles, both the rectangles get highlighted when I hover over any one of them. If I hover over any specific rectangle, I want only that rect to highlight. If I hover over the intersection I want both to highlight.

Comment: Oh-oh!...I misunderstand you goal, sorry!